# Adding an intersection results in strange error

Tags: typescript

Consider this:

```
type Foo<T> = Partial<T>;

function foo<T extends Foo<T>>() {
  /**/
}

function bar<T>() {
  return foo<T & ID>();
}

type ID = { id: number };
```

As soon as I add an intersection type to `Foo`, I get a strange unrelated error:

```
type Foo<T> = Partial<T> & {
  x?: string;
};

function foo<T extends Foo<T>>() {
  /**/
}

function bar<T>() {
  return foo<T & ID>();    <------ ERROR
}

type ID = { id: number };
```

The error is:

```
Type 'T & ID' does not satisfy the constraint 'Foo<T & ID>'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type '(T & ID)["id"] | undefined'.ts(2344)
```

With does the compiler suddenly complain about `id`, when I add a property `x`?

Comment: Generally speaking the compiler doesn't know how to manipulate unspecified generic types that much in order to see what's going to happen when they are specified later.  Often it will just defer such evaluation. There are *some* heuristics (which are not always right); so `T` is (erroneously) seen as assignable to `Foo<T>` because `T` has no known keys.  (You can see the problem because plugging `{x: number}` in for `T` will fail for `foo` but succeed for `bar`.) Once the compiler knows about `id`, it is unable to eagerly evaluate `(T & ID)["id"]` to compare it to `number`.

Comment: I don't know why you want `T extends Foo<T>` at all (seems unmotivated in the example) but if you're going to do this, you might need to use some type assertions or the like in locations where `T` is still generic.